# Finding largest prime factor for a number with python

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def prime(x):
    for a in range(2, x):
        if x%a == 0:
            break
    else:
        return x
num = 0 
largest = 0
for i in range(2, 600851475143):
    if 600851475143%i == 0:
        num = prime(i)
    
    if largest < num:
        largest = num
print(largest)
```

I got the answer but it's not running successfully I'm getting this error :
`'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'` 
Can you please tell me what's wrong with the code?
I can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ScottHunter, I'm removing my comment because it isn't helpful

Answer (score 1):

When `prime` is called with a non-prime, it never executes a `return` statement, and thus returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

prime does return None, if it stops with break.

Instead of break, you could use return 0. This won´t run into the same error and will not change largest, since largest>=0.

But I guess this is a very inefficient way to get the largest primefactor. It would probably be faster to factorize and then to look for the greatest factor.

Comment: yep i tried returning 0 before it breaks it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

def prime(x) calls `break` when `if x%a == 0:` is true, but can't return anything.

To solve this issue use:

```
def prime(x):
    for a in range(2, x):
        if x%a == 0:
            break
    return x
```

By the way: Finding Primefactors is more an recursive Problem than an interative.